# composer update can't download package over ssh. I always get a SVN authentification error

Tags: svn, ssh, composer-php

composer doesn't want to download packages from a subversion server. The problem only occurs over a ssh connection, on a testing server. Composer works perfectly on my local machine.

It seems like svn uses bad credentials, taken from some kind of cache but I can't figure how to make it work. It should ask me for my username and password, no?

Somebody can help?

Comment: Yes, if authentication fails, it should ask for username password. It shouldn't just crash without asking. Can you include more details about what you're doing, how you're doing it, and the exact error message you're getting. Also, can you try to do the same using the command line client (the `svn` command in a terminal)?

Comment: Like I said, I use Composer.phar (composer.phar update) some of the packages to be downloaded are git some are svn. The git packages work fine. The first svn package in the list gives the error : [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                  
Package could not be downloaded, svn: OPTIONS de 'https://xxxxx.slsapp.com/source/vendor-1/Symfony/Bundles/xxxxxx/trunk': Authorization Failed (https:  
  //xxxxx.slsapp.com)

Comment: Interesting facts : My colleague can make it work perfectly from her machine, logged on the same server via ssh. She's using Ubuntu. I work on MacOS. That's why I suspect some kind of bad ssh info or something.